# Automating Photoshop with JS

Tags: javascript, photoshop, photoshop-script

I had to place videos(*mp4*-files) in one photoshop document. I thought it would be easier to find a solution with *png/jpg*, and then project it on *mp4*. but the fact is that photoshop saving *png/jpg* and *mp4* in different ways. Therefore, despite the fact that there is an import solution, **I have difficulties with exporting *mp4* by code**.

I have 2 arrays of mp4 files and each mp4 from the first array needs to be overlaid on each of the second and saved by mp4. I solved the problem by uploading a video to an open photoshop file with a simple code:

```
function replaceContents(newFile) {
  var docRef = app.open(newFile);
  return docRef;
}

function importVideos(order_number) {
  var doc = app.activeDocument;
  var file = new File('E:/path/' + order_number + '.mp4');
  // open a new document with needed video
  var docTemp = replaceContents(file);
  // copy opend layer with video from new doc to my main doc
  var layer = docTemp.activeLayer.duplicate(doc.layerSets.getByName(color), ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND);
  // close new unnecessary doc
  docTemp.close(SaveOptions.DONOTSAVECHANGES);
  layer.name = order_number;
  return layer;
}
```

Here is the code for saving videos and in `doExport()` doc should be saved as a video.

```
function Saving(color) {
  var array1 = app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName('s');
  var array2 = app.activeDocument.layerSets.getByName(color);
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    array1.artLayers[i].visible = true;
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      array2.artLayers[i].visible = true;
      doExport();
      array2.artLayers[i].visible = false;
    }
    array1.artLayers[i].visible = false;
  }
}
```

So a new question: **how to export a video from photoshop with a code with the ability to specify the file name and the save path?**

P.S. if you do this through *Actions*, you can't enter input parameters like the name of the saved file, it seals the *Action* as you did it.

If you know how to create arguments for *Actions*, you are welcome!

Comment: Please don't ask for a hint, ask for a solution to a specific problem. Don't leave future visitors to your question guessing for the full solution.

Comment: Look here. [How to render mp4 animation from script](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/how-to-render-a-mp4-animation-from-jsx-script/m-p/11848198)